# Magento rewrite block doesn't work

Tags: magento

I need to override a method in a Magento core file, I am pretty sure I have done it the correct way and it is working on someone else's machine, but it's just not working on my own machine. We have the same environment. It's pretty weird I couldn't find out why and I have checked the file permissions, still don't see any light in solving the problem. Wonder has anyone run into the same problem? I am running 1.7

Many thanks!

--Update--

My custom block class (app/code/local/Company/Cms/Block/Page.php)

```
require_once("Mage/Cms/Block/Page.php");

class Company_Cms_Block_Page extends Mage_Cms_Block_Page
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        // my code
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Company/Cms/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Company_Cms>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Company_Cms>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <cms>
        <rewrite>
          <page>Company_Cms_Block_Page</page>
        </rewrite>
      </cms>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

app/etc/modules/Company_Cms.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Company_Cms>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Company_Cms>
  </modules>
</config>
```

This custom module isn't being executed at all as nothing changes unless I change code in core block class.

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: I believe it must be something to do with permissions or something, otherwise it wouldn't make sense if it works somewhere else.

Comment: Check the case sensitivity. I know you said it's the same environment, but when ever we get this, it's normally a case sensitive typo in the xml definitions such as a class rewrite. My mac normally doesn't care, our server does! Clear the caches, restart apache if APC installed, log out of admin and back in. Check system.log and exception.log, and php error log for errors.

Comment: You're asking a question while providing nothing of value to work with.  Show us what you are working with...

Comment: First step to debugging any rewrite. Can Magento see your Company_Cms module? (does it show up in the System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Disable Module Output menu?

Comment: @AlanStorm Yes, I can see the module but the code in the module never gets executed...

Comment: @Michael Second step to debugging any rewrite:  What class is Magento finding for the cms/page alias right here -- http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6631/can-not-override-sales-resouce-model-collection-class/6664#6664

Comment: @AlanStorm Sorry, but I still don't get where I went wrong...

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cache already? 

But what the heck? What's the require_once? that isn't needed or it is?